# Xib won't change background, but will show images

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I've created a xib file, which i'm using as a custom PullToRefresh through a library. However now that i've set everything up it does not seem to change the backgroundColor of the View? However if i go in the xib file and add a image it will show the image. What am i doing wrong?

```
public class PullToShowRefresher: PullToRefresh {
    public convenience init() {

        let refreshView =  NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).loadNibNamed("BERefreshView", owner: nil, options: nil).first as! BERefreshView
        let animator =  BEAnimator(refreshView: refreshView)
        self.init(refreshView: refreshView, animator: animator)
    }
}


class BERefreshView: UIView {



    // and others
}

class BEAnimator: NSObject, RefreshViewAnimator {
    private let refreshView: BERefreshView
    private let refreshViewHeight: CGFloat

    private var bubbleTimer: NSTimer?

    private let animationDuration = 0.3

    init(refreshView: BERefreshView) {
        self.refreshView = refreshView
        self.refreshViewHeight = refreshView.frame.size.height
    }

    func animateState(state: State) {
        switch state {
        case .Inital:
            initalLayout()
        case .Releasing(let progress):
           break
        case .Loading:
            break
        case .Finished:
            break
        }
    }

    func initalLayout() {
        refreshView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

in my view controller

```
    tableView.addPullToRefresh(PullToShowRefresher(), action: { [weak self] in
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self?.tableView.endRefreshing()
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is calling animateState(state: State) ?

Comment: i've added the code from viwController

Comment: its a delegate method in PullToRefresh library. However if i change background in interface builder. it still does not apply

Comment: I would use the view debugger and check the subviews that are in the view at runtime. http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6